# How to limit number of parallel tasks running?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, semaphore

I have code which listens to a folder and detects new files which are dropped in it.
Currently, each new file dropped will call the `WatcherOnCreated` method which creates a new Task to encrypt the file in parallel with others.

I want to limit the number of parallel file encryptions happening.

I tried using a semaphore with count 5 such that only 5 encryptions can be happening at the same time no matter how many files are dropped in.

However, it isn't working and causes my program to not respond.

```
class Test
{
        private static LimitEncryptionSemaphore;

        public Test()
        {
            LimitEncryptionSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
        }
        
        // some function which calls WatcherOnCreated
         
        private void WatcherOnCreated(string filePath, WatcherChangeTypes changeType)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

            Logger.Debug($"A created item {fileName} was detected in drop folder.");

            LimitEncryptionSemaphore.WaitAsync();
            // FireAndForget calls Task.Run(Func<Task>) with the callback function
            TaskFactory.FireAndForget(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await ExponentialBackoffPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        using (DeviceData deviceData = ReadDeviceData(filePath))
                        {
                            // Raise the event.
                            await OnDeviceDataAvailable(FolderDevice, deviceData);
                        }
                    });

                    if (FileSystem.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        // Delete the file once the handler is done.
                        FileSystem.DeleteFile(filePath);

                        Logger.Debug($"{filePath} was deleted.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Error(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Release semaphore
                    LimitEncryptionSemaphore.Release();
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: I think your question would be more on topic on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You should try posting there.

Comment: Your code limits to 10 instead of 5.

Comment: Note that while you have edited your question to try to make it less opinion-based (which is what drew the first two close votes), it still lacks a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem you describe, hence the third and final close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with the code:

1. The task returned from `LimitEncryptionSemaphore.WaitAsync` is ignored, instead of being `await`ed.
2. `LimitEncryptionSemaphore.WaitAsync` is called in a different method than `LimitEncryptionSemaphore.Release`.

Fix:

```
private void WatcherOnCreated(string filePath, WatcherChangeTypes changeType)
{
  string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
  Logger.Debug($"A created item {fileName} was detected in drop folder.");

  TaskFactory.FireAndForget(async () =>
  {
    await LimitEncryptionSemaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
      ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ...
    }
    finally
    {
      LimitEncryptionSemaphore.Release();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended using the WaitAsync and Release inside a deeper method of the try block (inside `OnDeviceDataAvailable`). Would I also need to dispose the semaphore?

Comment: @FryingPan: If you need to recreate the component in which it resides, then yes. You don't need to if the entire app is shutting down.

Comment: I `WaitAsync` and `Release` inside a function that is indeed called many times during the running of the app (every time a new file uploads, Task.Run is called to encrypt the file). I assume that this is what you mean by 'recreate the component'. Thus, in this case I would have to dispose of the semaphore in every thread after the release, correct?

Comment: @FryingPan: No. The `SemaphoreSlim` needs to be shared, and should only be disposed after everything is done using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, as you have no control over the amount of files dropped that you are better of using a concurrent queue and a loop processing the queued entries.

in the file watcher event queue the item in the queue and start a background worker to process the data. You can, if the queue gets too long start a new background process however you will likely starve the server processor if you do that.

You also have the possibility to loop using a Parallel.For with a parameter stating the maximum you like to start if the queue is longer than what you like, in your case 5.

Answer (score 0):

The .Net documentation for TaskScheduler has an example implementing a scheduler with a max degree of parallelism. Please take a look at that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0